# Gaming glossary

Tags: glossary

On one question I saw users using the word "mobs" - I have never heard this term, and got me thinking - is there glossary of game and gamedev terms that anyone has come across?

ps. what are mobs?

Comment: Might want to make this CW since it will be a list.

Comment: imho this looks more suitable for http://gaming.stackexchange.com/ mobs stand for monsters afaik, ks for kill steal, pk, player kill... but you may get a more complete list at the gaming section

Comment: It's not at all unusual for communities to develop **their own glossary** in their [meta site](http://meta.gamedev.stackexchange.com). See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40353/stack-overflow-glossary-dictionary-of-commonly-used-terms for reference.

Comment: @Robert the issue is that gaming jargon is very game-specific and is very disjoint from game developer jargon. The phrase the OP is asking about is more of the former category.

Answer (score 1):

This holds a pretty nice list of what you are looking for:
http://mmoterms.com/full-mmorpg-terms-glossary

There are still game specifics, etc...

Answer (score 1):

A mob is a "**mob** ile" unit. It was popular at least in the DIKU and derivative MUD's, but may have been used elsewhere, too.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a fairly significant issue.  A few years ago I was working on an MMO where most of the engineering had played one MMO, while most of design had played a different MMO.  There wasn't a lot of people who had played both.  As such there was a lot of terms that one group or the other assumed were rather common but were specific to that one game/genre.  Without the common language and common dictionary talking about design is much harder as so many concepts can be shortened to a quick abbreviation.  Anyone who has played an MMO with an aggression system will instantly know what you mean by 'taunt' even if the MMO doesn't use that as a term.  If you come from a JRPG background though, the concept is fairly meaningless.

Comment: That may be common on the player's side, using short words to describe something, but i dont think a company would use these terms on the development side specially. They would communicate using the proper words and from that create a new words for their games for example fire blast which is a fair used name becomes `Doom's Blade` which a player would later make into `hey how much dmg your DB does` so these are fairly player terms for gaming imho.

Comment: Well I think that's a problem that should be handled on a team or project basis.  Just make a wiki page or something that says what terms you're using and make sure everybody's bought in.

Comment: just makes my point, that a development team will talk things over...